# How to have Rails 5 inclusion validation accept either a word or it's plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, include, inclusion

I have been teaching myself Rails for a while and am making a cat based website based off of Hartl's tutorial for practice. I want all user's to have to include either the word "cat" or "cats" in their posts. To do this I thought it would be easiest to use the inclusion validation on my micropost model, however I am not sure how to have the validation work in the case that the user makes a post containing "cats" instead of "cat", or containing both words. I feel like I'm missing something pretty simple. Any help would be much appreciated!
Here is my micropost model file:

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates  :user_id, presence: true
  validates  :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 },
    inclusion: { in: %w(cat), message: "must contain the word cat" }
end
```

Comment: What about `inclusion: { in: %w(cat).flat_map {|s| [s, s.pluralize] }, message: "must contain the word cat" }`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Actually I realized a terrible flaw in my code, while the flat_map method works, the include validator returns an error if the post contains anything but the word cat or cats, really not sure how to fix this but by using validates_with and defining a custom class. Thanks for the help though! I didn't know about flat_map until now.

Comment: Hey, I hope you found out the solution. Let me know if you still stuck.